# My fullscreen app switches to lower resolution after killing it and starting it again

Tags: android, draw, screen-resolution

My phone Galaxy S8 has these screen resolutions: 720p, 1080p and 1440p. I almost always have 1440p selected and only use other for testing. I noticed that my app seems to switch to 1080p if I kill it and start it again. In other words it only works in my selected 1440p resolution after I restarted my phone and started my app.

To illustrate the problem I draw I circle at x=1080. If its closer to the center we are in 1440p, if its right on the edge we are in 1080p and if its not on the screen we are probably in 720p.
I restart my phone and start my app. Its closer to the center. I kill the app and start it again. Circle is now right on the edge. No matter how many times I kill and start it now, it will be on the edge. Now if I switch to 1080p in the setting and go back to the game, the circle will be gone, suggesting its not in 1080p actually. Now I kill my app and start it again still in 1080p mode and the circle is on the edge, where it should be. And if I switch to 1440p without killing my app the circle will be back close to the center of the screen where it should be.

In other words to make my game work at 1440p I must either launch it after restarting my phone or switch to 1080p, start it and switch to 1440p.
Changing/adding this in the manifest file doesn't help:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Is this an Android bug? Or I need to change something in my app to make it reliably launch in higher resolutions?

Comment: I realized that if I change application id of my game, Android will let me run it at 1440p. And if I change it back to the old id it will run at 1080p. I think what happened is I briefly experimented with some heavy computations, it ran slowly and Android just decided to put it on a naughty list of apps that are too slow for my device. Except I ran it like that maybe once. Is there a way to clear this app id in my OSes eyes? Moving to a different app id is problematic. Is there a way to disable this "feature"? I should be free to experiment on my own device as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is caused by Game Tools. I tested this an app that launches with Game Tools in the bar will run at a lower resolution.